# Почему не передаются данные через $_SESSION?

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуй, ХешКод! Скажите, почему данные не выводятся, делаю всё вроде правильно.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $name = $_POST["teen"];
    $_SESSION["text"] = $name;
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
    <form action = "index.php" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name "teen">
    <input type = "submit" value =  "Отправить">
    </form>

    <a href = "post.php">Перейти</a>
    </body>
    </html>

А вот тут должно выводится то что в $_SESSION

    <?php
    session_start();

    echo("Привет, " . $_SESSION["text"]);
    ?>
```

Но почему-то выводится пустой результат, однако если вместо:

```
$_SESSION["text"] = $name;
```

Написать:

```
$_SESSION["text"] = "ХешКод";
```

То страница всё выводит. Сразу пишу, я делал проверку пустое ли поле или нет.

Answer (score 3):

> `<input type = "text" name "teen">`

тут "=" пропущено. Может быть по этой причине?

Comment: Конечно в этом дело и сессию не надо 2 раза стартовать, как написали ниже

Answer (score 2):

Перед тем, как сделать это:

```
   $_SESSION["text"] = $name;
```

Выведите в окно браузера содержимое **$name**. Посмотрите, что да как. Если переменная **!=""**, то, скорее всего, вы забыли стартануть сессию в том файле, где идет присвоение. Это первая возможная ошибка. Вторая возможная ошибка может крыться в кодировке страницы, где выводится переменная сессии. Установить кодировку UTF-8. А вдруг проблема здесь?

Comment: Верно, а не подскажите где ошибка? Почему данные не помещаются в переменную?

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST["teen"];
```

А в `$_POST["teen"]` они правильно попадают?

Answer (score 0):

Если это один фаил кода, то  зачем запускать два раза `session_start();`? Возможно, проблема в этом.

Comment: Да не проблема уже решена, спасибо)